Multi meter ohmmeter is not reading resistance
I have a cheap multi meter.  It measures voltage fine, but when I put it on 20k ohms, it shows infinite.  I touch the probes together, it reads number then goes down to zero; however, when I go to test a resistor it just stays at infinite.  Is my meter broken?

Sounds like the definition of broken to me.  Make sure the battery is fresh, make sure the test leads are in good condition and make sure the resistance you're measuring is really in the right range.  If those things are all OK, then your range selector switch is probably the issue.

@JohnD -  Thanks for trying to help, but please remember that comments shouldn't be used to answer a question - that's not an allowed use of them. Please see here for why answering in a comment can be harmful to the site & here for more details of the allowed uses of comments. TY

@SamGibson Understood.  I used a comment because I have no idea if his meter is broken or not, or if he's using it improperly, or his battery is dead, etc.  So I do not consider my comment an answer to "Is my meter broken", only comments on things to try in order to debug the issue or suggest possible causes.

Thank you for responding I will look into it

@JohnD - Comments like that 1st one should be posted as an answer (where you can state assumptions, limitations e.g. these are just suggestions etc. - see here) as that isn't in one of the categories of allowed uses of a comment. || Answers don't have to be perfect - an answer saying that from experience the cause could be X or Y, check A, B and C, is fine. If it turns out that you're right, you can edit such an answer to say that following tests by the OP, problem K was confirmed. || Even if such an answer doesn't pinpoint the fault here, they can help future readers.

@JohnD - Or you could just ask questions to the OP in comments e.g. have you checked the battery, have you checked the test leads etc. The things that make the comment cross the line into being an answer (or, at least, no longer an allowed use of a comment) are the statement "Sounds like the definition of broken to me." because that answers the OP's question "Is my meter broken?" & also the statements "make sure the resistance you're measuring {...}" and "your range selector switch is probably the issue". Those are conclusions, not clarification questions nor constructive criticism. HTH TY

Even a low end multimeter should read resistance with an error not more than 1000 or 2000 ohm. Are you sure you used the correct scale of units of resistance? Is it possible to show a picture of your multimeter?

@SamGibson Got it, thanks for the clarification!

Not necessarily. Your resistor might be. Or just larger than 20k so it can't be measured with 20k range.

It's with in range

@RobertMesa How do you know if your only meter won't measure it?

I have another meter and I also know what measurement the resistor is

@RobertMesa Ok, so the batteries may be low and need changing, or the meter is damaged. Or just bad contact on the mode selector switch.
